# Finding the size of .net hashtable

Tags: .net, size

Finding the size of .net hashtable when deserialzing

If I read from a stream and get a hashtable out. Is their a good way to know how large the hashtable would be. Ie, if I look the file in a binary editor how many of the bytes represent this hashtable?  How does the Deserialize mehthod know what goes into the hash?

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
table = (Hashtable)formatter.Deserialize(FileStream);
```

Edit:
What I am trying to figure out is if I were to look at the file in a binary editor how much of that data in the filestream is my hashtable. Or can I do something like a sizeof() to find out the size (I suspect I can't).

Comment: @Maestro, what size are you looking for? The number of bytes of the serialized hashtable?

Comment: Even if you had a way to look into the binary that worked today, it could change as soon as the binary format changes.

Comment: @John. You mean if the format in the file changed, like add a new key,value? Or do you mean if .net changed the way this was stored?

Sorry for my ignorance I am just trying to understand.

Comment: Perhaps the binary formatter algorithm could change from version to version of the .NET framework, thereby changing the size of the serialized hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this snippet of code might help? Shameless borrowed from [Victor Garcia Aprea](http://weblogs.asp.net/vga/archive/2004/05/11/dontletthebinaryformattergetatit.aspx). The article suggests that the size variable will hold the number of bytes. Granted this is serialized to a string, and not binary as you're looking for.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ht.Add(i, (i*10000).ToString());
}

LosFormatter los = new LosFormatter(); //in System.Web namespace; used for ViewState
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
los.Serialize(sw, ht);
string resultSt = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

int size = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString().Length;

Console.WriteLine(size);
```

Comment: I think that is supposed to say:

    string resultSt = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    int size = resultSt.Length;